# Getting text out of an if statement

Tags: java, selenium

So I'm using Selenium and would like to grab certain information that is printed on a web page. Unlike a regular page which would print the text the information is displayed in a different manner. The source to the web page looks like this.

```
<div class="a">
    <script id="b">
        <div class="c">
            <div class="d">
                #if 
                    Print X.
                {else}
                    Print Y.
            </div class>
        </script>
    </div class>
</div class>
```

I'd like to get either X or Y based on whatever is printed, how can I get this information?

## EDIT:

My script tag looks like this

```
<script id="plansTemplate" type="text/template" defer="defer">
```

And when I run the following line of code,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='plansTemplate']")).getText();
```

I get the error

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='plansTemplate']"}

Comment: Using XPath is one way.

Comment: What would I set as the category and what would be the id?

Comment: Use the `id` of the `script` tag and get the second `div` child's data. You could also get the element by it's `class`, if that's easier and each `div` class is distinct. Another suggestion would be to fix your xml so that your closing tags match up..

Comment: I've edited the original post with the error.

Comment: That means the element does not exist at the time you fetch it. Is it inside a frame? Are you sure it's available when you check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read [By](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html), and [try](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html) -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("plansTemplate"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
String required_text = new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#b div.d"))).getText();

//do what ever you want with required_text
```